# Double slit experiment with slit having positional offset

Tags: optics, visible-light, double-slit-experiment, interference

For the double slit experiment, the slits are set up with middle part is positioned where the red line is. What happens if we move the middle part outwards to where the blue bar is? Would this still create an interference pattern?

[image: Red is the normal slit and blue is the new type of slit]

Comment: The blue-only setup slits look about 1.5 larger than the original ones, which should not prevent diffraction. The question deserves to be made more precise, though. Why do you expect interferences to vanish (or not to vanish) exactly? What is your conceptual problem here?

Comment: In normal double slit experiment, all 3 plates creating 2 slits are generally arranged in same place. What if we displace the middle plate out of that plane? will it create interference pattern? I hope question is clear now!

Comment: It's unclear where the light source, screen, and plane of double slit is.  As written, even with your comment, the question makes no sense.

Comment: The question does make sense, but the answer is just not very interesting -- the pattern will be about the same but slightly messed up by diffraction effects. Try playing with [this](http://www.falstad.com/ripple/) simulation, it doesn't have your exact setup but it has similar ones.

Answer (score 0):

Normally if we have an arrangement exactly like Young's double slit, light behaves as two point sources after passing through the slits. Two waves superpose on one another to give an interference pattern. Here as you move the middle plate the arrangement is not like the previous one. You can not call them slits. The light is first diffracted from the sharp point of the first displaced plate and then at the other plate. The waves after passing do not originate from point sources which is an essential condition for interference. Remember the rule for the division of the wave front, it says that to divide the wave front we need Young's double slit arrangement not the arrangement you propose. This arrangement gives neither a division of amplitude nor a division of wave front. So interference pattern is not possible. Hope you got it.

Comment: I edited your post for typos. Now, it seems this answer is the same as your previous one, only better explained. You should edit your first post instead of making a new one.

Comment: Is it clear to you or not

Answer (score -1):

No we can't see interfere pattern as the waves doesn't passes through slit of definite width. Waves obstruct at the first edge and finally other edge of the slit.

Comment: from top view, we know middle plate which creates 2 slits are skewed to left. But if we see from light perspective which doesn't see any difference as its coming from left side of the setup, i was not able to think that will it still create interference or not. Your answer is still not clear to me.